# Join some cell in file output excel android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cell, jxl

I have project android with file output excel. I just to show this file excel with display cell by cell. Now i want to display this file with join some cell, make marge & center, and add colour.

How source join some cell, make marge & center, and add colour in output excel like this?

My source now :

```
WritableSheet sheet = r_excel.createSheet("First Sheet", 0);
WritableSheet sheet1 = r_excel.createSheet("Second Sheet", 1);
Label label1 = new Label(0, 0, "Name");
Label label2 = new Label(1, 0, "Class");
Label label3 = new Label(2, 0, "Address");
sheet.addCell(label1);
sheet.addCell(label2);
sheet.addCell(label3);
r_excel.write();
r_excel.close();
```